# How to share variable to threads in smart way using pthreads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I want to synchroznie threads in C++ using pthreads in smart way.

I have one global variable:

```
int Resources = 0;
```

I have two thread functions:

```
void *incResources(void *arg)
{
   while(1)
   {
     pthread_mutex_lock (&resourcesMutex);
     Resources += 2;
     pthread_mutex_unlock (&resourcesMutex);
   }

pthread_exit((void*) 0);
}

void *consumeResources(void *arg)
{
   while(1)
   {
     pthread_mutex_lock (&resourcesMutex);
     Resources--;
     pthread_mutex_unlock (&resourcesMutex);
   }
   pthread_exit((void*) 0);
 }
```

And in main function I intialize two consuming threads and one incrementing thread:

```
pthread_mutex_init(&resourcesMutex, NULL);

pthread_create(&callThd[0], &attr, incResources, (void *)i);
pthread_create(&callThd[1], &attr, consumeResources, (void *)i);
pthread_create(&callThd[2], &attr, consumeResources, (void *)i);
```

I feel this so unefficient and it can be done better. Can you provide me some ideas? I've tried to use wait but i dont get it :/
Thanks!

Comment: What is your real problem? I'm sure you're not just incrementing and decrementing a variable.

Comment: Threading and efficiency is more dependant on the type of problem/work that consumers vs producers, than simply on numbers of them.  It could be that a one:one ratio makes sense.  We have no where near enough information to provide sensible insights.  EX: if all you're doing incrementing and decrementing an int, you would appear to have 1 too many consumers.  :)

Comment: I'd prefer using a class and pass an instance to the thread functions over using some global reference.

Comment: This looks like a typical producer/consumer problem, which is usually solved with a `queue` for storing the messages, and a `mutex/condition_variable` pair for synchronization. However, as @ChrisCM said we don't have enough information to give you a definitive answer.

Comment: @syam ... and wrap all of this together within one or more classes passed as instances to the various thread functions ...

Answer (score 0):

I you look for good and C++ ways, I strongly suggest to read  [C++ Concurrency in Action: by Anthony Williams](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988770) and leave pthread behind to use futures and similar high-level thing where you can. And if you must go with manual thread fiddling you can find good examples for that too.

Your problem statement is too vague for sensible advice -- the basic idea of good threading is to NOT have shared state at all, and for handshake situation like yours is likely, use some synchronized queue made for that very purpose.

Answer (score 0):

A smarter way to do this would use `std::mutex` and `std::thread` (or the Boost equivalents) so you don't need to unlock mutexes manually.

A condition variable will allow the consumers to block (without wasting CPU cycles) until there is work available for  them:

```
struct Resource
{
  int value;
  std::mutex mx;
  std::condition_variable cv;
};

void incResources(Resource& res)
{
   while(1)
   {
     {
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(res.mx);
       res.value += 2;
     }
     res.cv.notify_all();
   }
}

void consumeResources(Resource& res)
{
   while(1)
   {
     std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(res.mx);
     while (res.value == 0)
       res.cv.wait(l);
     res.value--;
   }
}
```

and in the main thread:

```
Resources res;
res.value = 0;
std::thread t1(incResources, std::ref(res));
std::thread t2(consumeResources, std::ref(res));
std::thread t3(consumeResources, std::ref(res));
// ...
t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you're using C++ there's no reason why to prefer native use of pthreads over the C++11 `std::thread` and STL synchronization classes.

If you can't use C++11 standards you should wrap the pthreads native interface to reasonable C++ class representations (see e.g. [`boost::thread`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread.html) or [STTCL Posix Thread](https://github.com/makulik/sttcl/tree/master/sttcl/PosixThreads) implementation).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to implement a producer and consumer, with the += thread creating work (numbers to be reduced) and the consumer taking them away.

Rather than having the consumer in a trivial spin loop like that, take a look at condition variables.

```
std::queue<Job*> queue;
pthread_mutex mutex;
pthread_cond cond;

void AddJob(Job* job) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    queue.push_back(job);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void* QueueWorker(void* /*threadInfo*/) {
    Job* job = NULL;
    for (;;) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while ( queue.empty() ) {
            // unlock the mutex until the cond is signal()d or broadcast() to.
            // if this call succeeds, we will have the mutex locked again on the other side.
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        }
        // take the first task and then release the lock.
        job = queue.pop();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        if ( job != NULL )
           job->Execute();
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

This scales to multiple consumers.

As an aside, while it can be useful to familiarize yourself with the pthreads implementation, you should probably look at one of the threading wrappers available. C++11 introduced std::thread and std::mutex, many people swear by boost, but personally I've found the OpenSceneGraph team's "OpenThreads" library one of the easiest and most elegant to work with.

Edit: here's a complete working implementation albeit with a somewhat artificial mechanism for ending the run.

```
#include <queue>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int jobNo = 0;
class Job {
public:
    Job() : m_i(++jobNo) { printf("Created job %d.\n", m_i); }
    int m_i;
    void Execute() { printf("Job %d executing.\n", m_i); usleep(500 * 1000); }
};

std::queue<Job*> queue;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void AddJob(Job* job) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    queue.push(job);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void* QueueWorker(void* /*threadInfo*/) {
    Job* job = NULL;
    for (;;) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while ( queue.empty() ) {
            // unlock the mutex until the cond is signal()d or broadcast() to.
            // if this call succeeds, we will have the mutex locked again on the other side.
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        }
        // take the first task and then release the lock.
        job = queue.front();
        queue.pop();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        if ( job == NULL ) {
            // in this demonstration, NULL ends the run, so forward to any other threads.
            AddJob(NULL);
            break;
        }
        job->Execute();
        delete job;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    pthread_t worker1, worker2;
    pthread_create(&worker1, NULL, &QueueWorker, NULL);
    pthread_create(&worker2, NULL, &QueueWorker, NULL);

    srand(time(NULL));

    // queue 5 jobs with delays.
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
        long delay = (rand() % 800) * 1000;
        printf("Producer sleeping %fs\n", (float)delay / (1000*1000));
        usleep(delay);
        Job* job = new Job();
        AddJob(job);
    }
    // 5 more without delays.
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
        AddJob(new Job);
    }
    // null to end the run.
    AddJob(NULL);

    printf("Done with jobs.\n");
    pthread_join(worker1, NULL);
    pthread_join(worker2, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```